# How to make my players hands shake in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shake

I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qvVNzsJyB0&t=20s) and saw the hand shaking effect that this game had, it made the animations and movement feel amazing. I would like to implement this in my game but I have no idea how I would go about that. The idea is that the hands shake slightly when the player is idle and then multiply when the player is moving or playing some animation. Any idea how I could do this?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfOHE.png) is how the arms and gun are setup,
I have no idea where to even start because I have never seen a game do this before and I could't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Two words: inverse kinematics.

Comment: I know that I should use inverse kinematics, I have them set up in my arms but I don't know how to make the arms shake

Comment: [Perlin noise](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html). Use a noise function to get values to set the position of the hands in x, y, and z

Comment: If you have IK all setup and ready to go, all you need to do is to animate the point of contact to simulate a handshake.